# Self-accepting an answer shows 0 rep in green instead of gray

Tags: bug, reputation, design, accepted-answer

When you accept an answer that you wrote for your own question (self-accepting), the event in the reputation history correctly shows 0 rep earned, but it incorrectly displays it in **green**:

[image]

...instead of **gray**, like other events that produce 0 rep, such as undoing and then redoing an action on a post, or "No net changes for this day":

[image]

Note: I'm only able to reproduce this when I'm signed in (*why?*).

Comment: Not a bug. In the old design, this would show with a green highlight.

Comment: @Sonic interesting point. What about the fact that it's only green when I'm signed in?